# Storing data using json-server in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json-server

I am new to using react and JSON.

I am using react with JSON-server for the database.

I have a output object of shapes which is again array of objects like this:

```
{
 "ArrowAnnotate": [],
 "Bidirectional": [],
 "EllipticalRoi": [{...}],
 "CircleRoi": [{...}],
 "FreehandRoi": [],
 "Length": [],
 "NonTarget": [],
 "RectangleRoi": [],
 "Angle": [],
 "TargetCR": [],
 "TargetNE": [],
 "TargetUN": []
}
```

I want to store this in a db.json file, but I am not getting the best way to start with.

Is looping over each array of objects and storing them in JSON according to shape a good idea? Because I also need to update the object values if that object is already there else, make a new object.

Any suggestions to store/update this type of format.

Answer (score 0):

you could check the post-call available https://github.com/typicode/json-server#plural-routes. You could update the database based on your requirement from react. If this does not allow you to format as per your requirement then you might have to spin up an express server to format them.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried this and it seems to be working fine with POST request but with PUT and DELETE it is throwing this error: "DELETE http://localhost:8080/EllipticalRoi?_id=29e4b8e8-320e-ad47-895d-a67cbc7a58a1 404 (Not Found)", But if I visited this URL I am getting data.